# Does an Orthogonal Projection map a basis of the space to a spanning set of the its subspace for a Hilbert Space?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces, projection

For finite dimensional vector spaces it is quite easy to prove that a surjective linear operator $V\mapsto W$ maps a basis of $V$ to a spanning set of $W$. Is this property still true for linear operators on Hilbert spaces? Specifically, I'm interested in the case of orthogonal projections and when the Hilbert space is separable.

Comment: I assume you mean "orthonormal basis?"  Of course a projection maps an abstract basis to a spanning set

Comment: Well it's not that obvious to me. Also I didn't ask for an orthonormal basis cause it looked like an even stronger statement. But yes, I'm also interested in that actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{e_i\}$ be a basis for $V$.  Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$, and $p: V \rightarrow W$ a projection, i.e. a surjective linear map such that $p^2 = p$.

Every element $w$ of $W$ is expressible as $\sum\limits_i c_i e_i$ for unique scalars $c_i$, almost all zero.  Then

$$w = p(w) = \sum\limits_i c_i p(e_i).$$

This shows that $\{ p(e_i)\}$ spans $W$.

*Similar statement for separable Hilbert spaces*:

Let $e_1, e_2, e_3, ...$ be an orthonormal basis for $V$.  Let $W$ be a closed subspace of $V$, and let $p: V \rightarrow W$ be a bounded linear operator such that $p = p^2$.  For every element $w \in W$, there exist unique scalars $c_i$ such that in the norm topology on $V$,

$$w = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^nc_i e_i.$$

Then also $w = p(w) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^nc_i p(e_i)$, this being a norm limit in $W$.

Comment: This answers my question, thanks! Looks like it was easy indeed. As I said in my comment I would also be interested in the stronger statement that $p(e_i)$ is also an orthonormal basis for $W$ if $e_i$ is an orthonormal basis for $V$ (if we exclude the vectors for which $p(e_i) = 0$ and $p(e_i) = p(e_j),i\neq j$). The closest thing I think I've found is that this may be true if a restriction of the basis of $V$ to $W$ already is a basis for $W$. Am I correct?

Comment: Yeah, I think you can always remove a set of the $p(e_i)$ so that the remainder is an orthogonal basis.  You need to renormalize them to be orthonormal.